# php upload code not working

Tags: php

I am trying to upload image file via PHP script. the problem is this that the file fields are 36 in number and only 28 works fine and remaining 8 could not be uploaded. If I delete some fields then they work. Otherwise, they do not work.

Have anybody a solution?. I would be very thankful.

Comment: How did you find 28 works and the rest of them not ? Are these all input fields for files ?

Comment: please post your codes... we can't help you if you will just post your problem here

Answer (score 0):

there may be a limit of your webserver. If you are using apache take a look in `php.ini` (`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`)

For more information please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

check the following configs in your php.ini:

```
max_execution_time  
post_max_size  
upload_max_filesize
```

Comment: Since PHP 5.2.12, max_file_uploads also affects the uploading.

Comment: i have checked that but it is giving the same problem.